# Ionic framework UI router bug in Drawer side menu content?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I've been coding an Ionic application using Intel XDK and I'm experiencing a weird issue using the Ionic framework. I am using nested states inside the side content of my drawer template and found a weird behaviour with the latest version of Ionic (1.2.4) which is pulled using Bower.

With the latest version I was getting a weird behaviour where when transition from state 1 to state 2 would look something like this: [weird bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBk11.png)

Also when in State 2 the side content would no longer be able to swipe the side drawer open as it did in the previous state.

This is a link to the plunker were it uses the old 1.0.0 beta version of ionic http://embed.plnkr.co/mX9DJRYMfTNHz0bYyMgw/

The state transitions correctly and the second state still allows for the drawer to be swiped open. I obviously don't want to use an older version of ionic because it doesn't support fancy things like pop overs that I would like use in the app.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide a plunker with ionic 1.2.4 that's reproducing your problem?. Also verify that your CSS files from Ionic are also updated. Even when you use SASS, you need to compile your CSS again so the new CSS changes are applied.

Comment: Sure. I can try to see if I can include it in another plunker

Comment: I don't have enough points to post 2 links so here is the link for you sir.
https://embed.plnkr.co/WuPJCoo2FQV1bkR0gvLj/

Comment: Also did you notice how the view has that weird grey transition?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, For the new version of ionic every state transition is cached. When the state transition occurs the side drawer is left open. This is why in the emulator you see the a weird layer lingering but don't see it on the phone. To close the drawer you must use the menu-close directive. I inserted it inside
`<a menu-close ui-sref ="state2">`

The menu-close directive will reset the entering view’s
history stack, making the new page the root of the history stack.